# How to make javascript function can use after dot

Tags: javascript

I'm doing firebase project these days, and i got a question about something.

```
var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("population", ">", 100000)
```

Those where() are stick together after dot and i have no idea.
How can i make function or class like that? I don't even know how to search !

I tried to make classes and unnamed functions but it doesn't work.

If i get to know about it, it'll be very useful for me. I really want to know.

Please help please

Comment: Your question is very unclear, can you please make your question self explainable by adding some examples instead of describing about it?

Comment: i want to make like this
function foo() {}
foo().foo().foo()

Comment: You can search about chaning methods in javascript

Comment: In Javascript this is called "method chaining".

Comment: Please refer the link for more details. https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Comment: thank u all thak u !! im very happy now ! :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something akin to the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).  The idea is to return the object after appending a condition.

Example code (language agnostic):

```
def where(condition){
    self.appendCondition(condition)
    return self  // Important part
}
```

The `return self` enables to chain methods on the same object.  Each one returns itself with the new condition appended.

Comment: If you feel the answer helps you and may help others, please consider marking it as accepted.